# ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 7 elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius=500):

    venues_list=[]
    for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
        print(name)

        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
            CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION, lat, lng, radius, LIMIT)

        results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0]['items']

        venues_list.append([( name, lat, lng, v['venue']['name'], v['venue']['location']['lat'], v['venue']['location']['lng'], v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])


    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
    nearby_venues.columns = ['Neighborhood', 'Neighborhood Latitude', 'Neighborhood Longitude', 'Venue', 'Venue Latitude', 'Venue Longitude', 'Venue Category']


    return(nearby_venues)
```

and when i call the above function

```
toronto_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=df['Neighborhood'], latitudes=df['Latitude'],longitudes=df['Longitude'])
```

I got the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-0a244f551e86> in <module>
      2 #nearyby_venues
      3 #toronto_venues = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0, 7)))
----> 4 toronto_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=df['Neighborhood'], latitudes=df['Latitude'],longitudes=df['Longitude'])

<ipython-input-42-217083dbcb80> in getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius)
     14 
     15     nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
---> 16     nearby_venues.columns = ['Neighborhood', 'Neighborhood Latitude', 'Neighborhood Longitude', 'Venue', 'Venue Latitude', 'Venue Longitude', 'Venue Category']
     17 
     18 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   5285         try:
   5286             object.__getattribute__(self, name)
-> 5287             return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   5288         except AttributeError:
   5289             pass

pandas\_libs\properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _set_axis(self, axis, labels)
    659 
    660     def _set_axis(self, axis, labels) -> None:
--> 661         self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
    662         self._clear_item_cache()
    663 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
    176         if new_len != old_len:
    177             raise ValueError(
--> 178                 f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
    179                 f"values have {new_len} elements"
    180             )

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 7 elements
```

From the stack trace i understand that, the problem is occurring due to the `nearby_venues` dataframe, the way i am assigning the columns is the main reason behind the error. What can i do to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try checking the result from the list comprehension? Did you try checking the dataframe before attempting to assign columns?

Comment: I did check both the list comprehension and the dataframe. if i remove that assigning column line, the error disappeared.

Comment: Right; the point is that the dataframe looks right to you, but it's not one for which that column assignment is valid. You should show what the dataframe looks like before the assignment.